# Slickgrid autoEdit and selecting range of cells

Tags: slickgrid

I am trying to use [autoEdit = true] and then trying to select multiple cells with a mouse and I can't get it to work. It seems like I can only achieve this when pressing the escape key prior to selecting any cells.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> is helping to exit autoEdit mode.
However Copy-Paste doeswn't work. I have just tried latest example https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-spreadsheet.html